# Using sed to transform json

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to use sed to transform this json:

```
{
  "terraform_version": "0.14.8",
  "terraform_revision": "",
  "provider_selections": {
    "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread": "1.3.0",
    "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm": "2.47.0",
    "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/cloudinit": "2.1.0",
    "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/external": "2.0.0",
    "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes": "2.0.2",
    "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local": "2.0.0",
    "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null": "3.0.0",
    "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template": "2.2.0",
    "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls": "3.0.0"
  },
  "terraform_outdated": false
}
```

to look like this:

```
{
  "terraform_version": "0.14.8",
  "terraform_revision": "",
  "provider_selections": "{\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread\":\"1.3.0\",\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm\":\"2.47.0\",\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/cloudinit\":\"2.1.0\",\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/external\":\"2.0.0\",\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes\":\"2.0.2\",\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local\":\"2.0.0\",\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null\":\"3.0.0\",\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template\":\"2.2.0\",\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls\":\"3.0.0\"}",
  "terraform_outdated": "false"
}
```

Essentially, provider_selections should be encapsulated in quotes and the quotes inside of it escaped. I also need the terraform_outdated value to be a string.

I attempted this:

```
cat jsondata.json | sed 's/{/"{/2' | sed 's/}/"}/1'
```

but I cannot figure out the rest.

Comment: Use a tool that's designed for the job, such as `jq`.

Comment: `jq` does not work with github runners so I am trying to come up with a work around. I have reported the issue: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2287

Comment: Reading your ticket linked above: That's not a jq error; It comes from something else. (It's a JavaScript stack trace, but jq isn't written in JavaScript).

Comment: With respect to that ticket: `terraform version -json | tee >(cat >&2) | (jq . || cat >/dev/null)` might give us more to go on to figure out what's wrong, btw. But in general, I'd be a lot happier trying to debug "why doesn't jq work in my github runner environment?" than "how can I edit JSON with sed?". The latter is something that simply Should Not Be Done.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use python :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
python -c "import json,sys
data=json.loads(open(sys.argv[1]).read())
data['provider_selections'] = json.dumps(data['provider_selections'])
print(json.dumps(data))
" data.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed, it is as following:

```
sed -r '/: \{/{x;N;:L;N;s/},/},/;TL;s/\"/\\\"/g;x;G;s/\n *//g};s/: ([^\"].*[^,])(,)?$/: \"\1\"\2/' file.json
```

Expanded to multiple lines

```
sed -r '
/: \{/{
  x
  N
  :L
    N
    s/},/},/
  TL
  s/\"/\\\"/g
  x
  G
  s/\n *//g
}
s/: ([^\"].*[^,])(,)?$/: \"\1\"\2/
' file.json
```

However, It is not versatile to use sed for format conversion like the above...

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is acceptable/available.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ed -s file.json <<-'EOF'
  g/: {/+1;/},/-1s/\"/\\\"/g
  g/: {/+1;/},/-1s/[[:blank:]]*//
  g/: {/+1;/},/s/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}//
  g/: {/;/},/j
  .,+s/\(.*\) \({\?.*}\?\)/\1 "\2"/
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

If the output is correct just change `Q` to `w` to edit the file inplace.

Only tested on GNU `ed`.